# using string to identify the elements of a listView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

As the question suggests, is it possible to identify the elements of a listView using string ids or something similar to id? I know the typical signature is

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {...}
```

But I need to have string ids or such. How would I do that?

**Elaboration (sorry if still unclear)**

The problem is my underlying list is a rotating list (i.e. circular list)

```
myList.addFirst(myList.deleteLast());
```

So the id/index of an item keeps actually floating around. But I need an id that is essentially a part of the element so that no matter the rotation, I can always retrieve the exactly element I mean to.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Give an example of the "string ids" you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Array List of strings. Add the strings id for listview in it.

Add a hidden textview in your listitems.

Add all the string id from Array List to your listview hidden textview.

Access the string id as below :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    TextView anyId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.anyID);
    String val_Id = anyId.getText().toString();
```

Using ArrayList allows to handle dynamic listview.

Comment: I am going to try this.

Comment: @sankyjain : "Add a hidden textview in your listitems." - That's a hack and totally unnecessary - any class which extends `View` can have a tag set using `setTag(...)`. Having a hidden `TextView` will create an overhead when it comes to inflating the list item view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of string ids for your listview. In onItemClick, you can use the position to assess your string array. As the list items and your string will be of same size, it should have one to one mapping.

I hope you understand what I mean..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a String row ID kindly get the position then convert it into string.